# efficiency of jquery toggler

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the link to my code: http://jsbin.com/edago3/edit

I would love to find out what improvements could be made to make it smaller and more efficient.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of improvements you can make if you're looking for more concise code, [you can see a full updated sample here](http://jsbin.com/edago3/3/edit).  I'll list the main areas you can save code on below (for equivalent functionality of course).

The main bits:

```
$($li).children('a').after(
  $(document.createElement('span'))
  .html("&nbsp; toggler &nbsp;")
  .addClass("gm-toggler")
  .hide()
);
```

Can be shortened to...

```
$li.children('a').after(
  $('<span>', { html: "&nbsp; toggler &nbsp;", 'class': "gm-toggler"}).hide()
);
```

---

This...

```
$li.hover(function() {
  $('.gm-toggler', this).show();
}, function(){
  $('.gm-toggler', this).hide();
});
```

Can be shortened to...

```
$li.hover(function(){
  $('.gm-toggler', this).toggle();
});
```

---

This...

```
if($(this).parent('li').hasClass('active')){
  // ... remove its active class ...
  $(this).parent('li').removeClass('active');
} else {
  // ... otherwise give it an active class.
  $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
}
```

Can be shortened to....

```
$(this).parent('li').toggleClass('active');
```

It's probably better to ask which parts you have questions on, the relevant documentation for the methods I used can be found here: [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/), [`jQuery(html, props)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

Comment: Thank you Nick. This is precisely what I was looking for. My only question is whether or not your method of creating the span is more efficient than document.createElement().

Comment: @Greg-J - There's a *very* small difference either way, just a more concise syntax way of doing it...if you're creating *lots* of them it'll move towards being faster since the created element is cached and cloned, if you did `$('<span class='gm-toggler'>&nbsp; toggler &nbsp;</span>')` it would be much faster, since you're getting even more benefit from the caching.

Answer (score 0):

Looks well written to me, nice job!  The only small thing I found that could be improved is line 17, change:

```
.html("&nbsp; toggler &nbsp;")
```

to:

```
.text("toggler")
```

and then pad `.gm-toggler` on the left and right with CSS.

Using `.html` relies on `.innerHTML` and will be slower than a standard Javascript text insertion (but it would write out the `&nbsp;` as text, hence the padding, which is better for separating presentation anyway).

Also, in the line just before that, you can just say `$('<span>')` and jQuery will construct it exactly as you've written.  Just more readable.